# Make `locate` able to search files on external HDD

Tags: locate, removable-storage

If I understand correctly, the database `locate` relies on is just for files on partitions of internal HDDs. I wonder if it is possible to use `locate` on external HDDs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The locate database is generally configured to omit files on removable disks, since they can't be assumed to be there later. It can be configured through a file such as `/etc/updatedb.conf` (the location depends on which of the several `locate` programs you use and how it is configured by your distribution).

For a removable disk, it is probably better to keep the database in a separate file. Run

```
updatedb --localpaths=/media/my_removable_disk --output=/var/cache/locate/my_removable_disk.locatedb
```

to update the database. Add `/var/cache/locate/my_removable_disk.locatedb` to the environment variable `LOCATE_PATH`; for reasonably recent versions of GNU locate, an empty path component stands for the default path, so you can use

```
export LOCATE_PATH=:/var/cache/locate/my_removable_disk.locatedb
```

If you want to keep the locate database on the removable disk, don't add the path to `LOCATE_PATH`, because `locate` stops looking if one of the database files is missing. A wrapper script would be better:

```
locates () {
  locate "$@"
  for d in /media/*; do
    locate -d "$d/.locatedb" "$@"
  done
}
```

Comment: Just a note for future reference, the command is a tad different for mlocate users: updatedb --database-root /media/my_removable_disk --output=/var/cache/locate/my_removable_disk.locatedb --prunepaths "" --prunefs ""

Comment: see a [lesmana's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60202/updatedb-locate-command-problem-files-from-external-hard-drive-are-no-longer), it worked for me, in particular his point 2. I am on a Fedora 30.

Answer (score 5):

The config file is here: `/etc/updatedb.conf`, so if you didn't add anything, just mount your HDD, and do `updatedb`, then you would be able to search for files on external HDD partitions.

Comment: Thanks! If I disconnect my external HDD from my computer, the config file will be updated automatically later to remove info about the external HDD?

Comment: @Tim, no, that's not possible at this moment, infomration won't update unless you do `updatedb` again.

Comment: @Tim updatedb generate a static db file

Comment: But on my Ubuntu 12.04, the database is updated automatically and periodically.

Comment: @Tim yes, there's a cron job that does `updatedb` daily

Comment: is there some way to prevent disconnected media having its files removed from the updatedb database?